# Parse: Retrieving Child from Parent

Tags: android

I am using [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) and created a one-to-one relationship between two models (a location has a queue).  How can I retrieve an attribute of the queue using just the location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started using Parse. According to their [Android documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide), you need to add the queue ParseObject to the location ParseObject before you store them (or vice versa).

Assuming you put the relationship between the two in the location object, , you should be able to pull the queue with something like this:

**Storing:**

```
// Create location
ParseObject location = new ParseObject("Location");
location.put("foo", "bar");

// Create queue
ParseObject queue = new ParseObject("Queue");
queue.put("name", "Ben");

// Store the queue in the location (location will contain a pointer to queue)
location.put("Queue", queue);

// Save both location and queue
location.saveInBackground();
```

**Retrieving:**

```
// Retrieve location using objectId
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Location");
query.getInBackground("QkKt30WhIA", new GetCallback() { // objectId!
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // Location found! Query for the queue
            object.getParseObject("Queue").fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    // Queue found! Get the name
                    String queueAttr = object.getString("name");
                Log.i("TEST", "name: " + queueAttr);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            // something went wrong
            Log.e("TEST", "Oops!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I tried to do this, but I didn't understand how it would know which queue I was referring to (since queue is never instantiated; my fetched location doesn't have a parse object named "queue."  

I ended up just creating my own relation manually by creating a column in my queue model with the name of the location.  That way if I know the location, I could just search for the same string in my queue model.  It works, but it's not a very elegant want to do it...

I also tried to get the pointerID from my Parse table but that didn't work either.

Comment: When you are storing your location ParseObject, are you also creating a queue ParseObject and putting it into the location ParseObject before calling location.saveInBackground()? I'm trying code and will paste something in if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
        // create qLocation
        ParseObject qLocation = new ParseObject("QLocations");
        qLocation.put("name", qname);
        qLocation.put("streetAddress", streetAddress);
        qLocation.put("cityState", cityState);

        // create qLine               
        ParseObject qLine = new ParseObject("Lines");
        Random r = new Random();
        qLine.put("length", r.nextInt(10)); //set line length to a random number between 0-10
        qLine.put("qName",qname);

        // add relationship
        qLine.put("parent", qLocation);

        // save line and location
        qLine.saveInBackground();
```

In the end, line qline.put("parent", qLocation); didn't end up mattering because I had no idea how to use that relationship to get the queue from a given location.  So I just ended up using the column "qName" in qLine to check which queue was associated with which location.